# View current Azure Managed Backups configuration in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-backups

I have inherited a SQL Server 2008 database (with a 2016 msdb database)  that uses Azure Managed Backups. The database is in Simple recovery mode.

The backup is running every five minutes.  The generated query is a BACKUP DATABASE TO URL and seems to be doing a full backup every time.

I have two questions that do not seem to be in MS documentation:

1. For SQL Server 2008 databases in Simple recovery mode, is the `@log_backup_freq` parameter on `managed_backup.sp_backup_config_schedule` causing a full backup to be performed instead of the log backup? This is OK, I would just like to confirm.
2. How can I view the current azure managed backup configuration? There are various stored procedures to create backups and set the parameters, but I can't find one to view the current configuration. Nothing in SSMS (17.2) seems to show these settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. For SQL Server 2008 databases in Simple recovery mode, is the @log_backup_freq parameter on managed_backup.sp_backup_config_schedule causing a full backup to be performed instead of the log backup? This is OK, I would just like to confirm.

Please reference the document [managed_backup.sp_backup_config_schedule (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/managed-backup-sp-backup-config-schedule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

@log_backup_freq

This determines the frequency of transaction log backups. These backups happen at regular intervals rather than on the schedule specified for the database backups. @log_backup_freq can be in minutes or hours and 0:00 is valid, which indicates no log backups. Disabling log backups would only be appropriate for databases with a simple recovery model.

It won't cause the full backup.

> 2. How can I view the current azure managed backup configuration? There are various stored procedures to create backups and set the parameters, but I can't find one to view the current configuration. Nothing in SSMS (17.2) seems to show these settings.

Use this stored procedure to review or determine the current SQL Server Managed Backup to Microsoft Azure default configuration settings for the instance of SQL Server.

```
managed_backup.fn_backup_db_config ()
```

[image]

Ref: [managed_backup.fn_backup_instance_config (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/managed-backup-fn-backup-instance-config-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the function, that's exactly what I needed.
Regarding the log backups, if the DB is in simple mode, what happens?  Using Activity monitor, this is called every 5 minutes:

BACKUP DATABASE @db_name TO URL = N'https://url/file.bak' WITH STATS = 5, NAME = 'backup name', COMPRESSION

If this isn't a full backup, what is it?  It takes about a minute to run.

thanks!

Comment: @Jim88888 You're welcome, I'm glad to help you. In usually, full backup every 7 days, log backup every 5 minutes. I really have not more experience about simple recovery mode. But from the document [Backup to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-managed-backup-to-microsoft-azure?view=sql-server-ver15#backup-strategy), it gives us the conditions about when it's full backup or log backup.

Comment: Hi @Jim88888, If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members.  And people are more glad to help the people when their answer could be marked. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, you've been very helpful!